# How would I calculate how many selectable values would be left in a numpy array given a finite budget constraint and cost of each value

Tags: python, numpy, dynamic-programming

Say I had a simple numpy array representing the cost of each item

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

and a finite budget of 5.

I want to return another numpy array that tells me how many selectable items would be left over for each item selected.

So for example in this case the array returned would be:

```
y = np.array([3,2,2,1,0])
```

Because if I selected the first item of cost 1, I can still take the 2nd, 3rd, of 4th items while staying less than or equal to the budget constraint. If I select the second item of cost 2, I can still take the 1st or 3rd items. If I select the third item of cost 3, I can still take the 1st or 2nd items. If I select the 4th item, I can only still take the 1st item. And of course if I select the item that costs 5, I can't select any other items given a finite budget constraint of 5.

How would you go about this in an efficient way without doing an explicit for loop over each item?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Numpy broadcasting

```
m = (x[:, None] + x) <= 5
y = m.sum(1) - m.diagonal()
```

#### Explanations

Calculate the outer sum on array `x` using numpy broadcasting

```
>>> x[:, None] + x

array([[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

Compare the outer sum with budget constraint to create a boolean mask

```
>>> m = (x[:, None] + x) <= 5
>>> m

array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Now take `sum` along `axis=1` on this boolean mask to get the total number of selectable items including the current selected item

```
>>> m.sum(1)

array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Subtract the `diagonal` values from the above calculated `sum` to exclude the current selected item.

```
>>> m.diagonal().view('i1')

array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0])


>>> y = m.sum(1) - m.diagonal()
>>> y

array([3, 2, 2, 1, 0])
```